# How to generate Preload animated gif for Internet-Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, preloader

freakin' out because i didn't manage to create a preloader, which is working in internet explorer. it is a real small preloader (10x10px), which is shown in a textfield after the user started a search.

i first implemented a css-spinner from here: http://cssload.net/ which looks good everywhere but doesn t work in ie at all.

afterwards, i generated one animated gif at http://ajaxload.info/ , but the results are looking pretty ugly in small size. it doesn t make a difference, if the gif is transparent or not...

anyone a good idea for that? 
thanks,
k

EDIT: mootools is supported, but i do not want a small flash-preloader for that case!

Comment: Looking ugly in small size? Are you client-side-resizing the animation?

Comment: I think this would be helpful if you put this in a JSFiddle or something like it so we can see what's going on.

Comment: i do yes, but it's not much and even in original size they don t look that good..

Comment: "Not much"? Even a one-pixel client-side re-size will turn any non-JPEG into an utter crapfest. *Especially* GIF animations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for all comments and infos!

i guess the problem was the transparency of the preloader. the background of the text input is grey, so with transparent gif i had white pixel at the "corners" during the animation. i just choosed the grey color as background-color from the gif, and it looks ok. thanks eyerbody!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this one?

[preloaders.net](http://www.preloaders.net/)

there are many modification possibilities and it looks nice in small size as you can scale the image to the size you prefer.

implementing a gif as part of a veil component you are viewing above the component you are loading or which is processing the request will work on every browser.

Comment: yeah, found that too. same result than ajaxload.info

Comment: what exactly doesnt work or look ugly, generating a 10x10 gif loader does not look ugly in any way